# Using Excel Conditional formatting on a range, "applies to" a variable number of rows

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to have the value (X) in a cell $A:$A conditionally format cells on (X) number of rows down.

E.g. "Applies to" $B1:$B( ROW() + (X) )

[This is what I'm hoping to get;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMy5z.jpg)